# This functions runs when the page loads, but only alerts 1 and 2 occur-- not alert 3. What bug is preventing alert 3 from executing?

Tags: javascript, sql, xml, ajax, web

When the page loads, this function is run, but only gets to alert 2, I suspect it doesn't reach alert 3 due to a bug in the previous line `var id_array = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id");`. I have tried researching `getElementsByTagName()` to see if I am using it correctly and I still feel like I am.

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    alert("2");
        var id_array = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id");
    alert("3");
    for(id in id_array)
    {
        // do something with the id 
    }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "xmlDoc.xml", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(); 
alert("1");
```

this is a sample of the xml document it should read from. The actual file generates x amount of "id"s with varying information from an sql database.

```
<id>
    <name><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["name"]; ?>]]></name>
    <latitude><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["latitude"]; ?>]]></latitude>
    <longitude><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["longitude"]; ?>]]></longitude>
    <color><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["color_id"]; ?>]]></color>
    <color_r><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["red"]; ?>]]></color_r>
    <color_g><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["green"]; ?>]]></color_g>
    <color_b><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["blue"]; ?>]]></color_b>
    <text><![CDATA[<?php echo $user_array["comment"]; ?>]]></text>
</id>
<id>
    <name><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["name"]; ?>]]></name>
    <latitude><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["latitude"]; ?>]]></latitude>
    <longitude><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["longitude"]; ?>]]></longitude>
    <color><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["color_id"]; ?>]]></color>
    <color_r><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["red"]; ?>]]></color_r>
    <color_g><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["green"]; ?>]]></color_g>
    <color_b><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["blue"]; ?>]]></color_b>
    <text><![CDATA[<?php echo $user_array["comment"]; ?>]]></text>
</id>
<id>
    <name><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["name"]; ?>]]></name>
    <latitude><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["latitude"]; ?>]]></latitude>
    <longitude><![CDATA[<?php echo $query_array["longitude"]; ?>]]></longitude>
    <color><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["color_id"]; ?>]]></color>
    <color_r><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["red"]; ?>]]></color_r>
    <color_g><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["green"]; ?>]]></color_g>
    <color_b><![CDATA[<?php echo $color_array["blue"]; ?>]]></color_b>
    <text><![CDATA[<?php echo $user_array["comment"]; ?>]]></text>
</id>
```

So my EXPECTED behavior would be that id_array (in this example) gets 3 cells (one per  occurence) and each of those cells contains all the data within the  tags.

But again, I suspect a bug in the assignment of id_array is keeping anything from happening.

Any help would be great!

Comment: try doing console.log on your `xmlDoc` object and see what it puts out in the console.

Comment: Is there an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: can't really tell without seeing xmlhttp.responseXML.. it does contain id tags like <id>...</id> right?

Comment: I think you need to set the Content Type to 'text/xml' instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: I looked at an error log and noticed that it shows... "Uncaught TypeError: Object <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>: <results> <id> ... </id><id>...</id> </results> has no method 'getElementsByTagName' "

Comment: when outputting xmlDoc to console i get--

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <results>
    <id> ... </id>
    <id> ... </id>
    <id> ... </id>
    </results>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',  'text/xml');
```

and see if

```
xmlhttp.responseXML
```

does not yield `null` resulting in an error when trying to do `.getElementsByTagName("id")`.

Comment: I did so, I I get the error 

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null map_functions.js:96
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange map_functions.js:96"

Comment: @user1707468 as i said, `xmlhttp.responseXML` returns `null` for you - thus the error. Are you doing a Cross-Domain request?

Comment: It appears it does, but no, the files are all on my server.

Comment: Sorry, just finished speaking with a colleague, the sql database being accessed is on a different server. I added a php require to gain access to that database and the error has gone away. Thanks a bunch.